# Cannot write files

Tags: permissions, mount, read-only

Someone else (who is not available) set up an Ubuntu server.  It is hosting a web server (possibly Apache).  I am not able to write new versions of the web pages.  I logged in as root and went to one of the website folders and entered `ls -la`

It showed that the folder and its sub-folders were listed as read/write.  I then entered `touch test.txt` and got the response "touch: cannot touch 'test.txt": Read-only file system". I used FileZilla and downloaded a "mounts" file:

```
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1999224k,nr_inodes=499806,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=404060k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/mapper/w1itsvub01--vg-root / ext4 ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot ext2 rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl 0 0
lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs fuse.lxcfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/0 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=404060k,mode=700 0 0
```

Lines 6 and 10 say "ro" but the file is meaningless to me.  I also tried `findmnt -A` but got "-bash: /bin/findmnt: Input/output error".  I did `compgen -c` thinking that maybe findmnt was not included in this installation of Ubuntu.  It shows up in the list.

What should I be doing to diagnose the problem of not being able to write files to a folder?

Comment: Is the website located under the root (/) filesystem? Or in one of the LXC containers (lxcfs)? Or an attached device (fusefs)?

Comment: @user535733 Good observation. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the server was having problems, error logs filled up the available space and it set itself to read only until the problems could be resolved and space cleared (or something along those lines).  Our solution was to spin up IIS on a Windows server and shut down the Linux server.